# Hide first "Zero" on a number value with xml

Tags: xml, numbers, format, zero

i'v got a problem...
I Need to show some prices in my website from database.
I'm using this function to show them:

```
<xsl:value-of select="entry/name"/>
```

My problem is this: due to "sorting reasons" I need to enter values like this:
0800 (for 800 dollars).
Are there an xml filter/function which can remove the first number if it is a "0" (zero)?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your name contains only decimal digits, just do

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(entry/name, "#")'/>
```

It will strip any zeroes from the start of a number.